# javascript: is it possible to target div of another file?

Tags: javascript, php

Let me explain the purpose of this. I'm using some CMS and I'm trying to customize it with php scripts of my own that I embedded to the home page with IFRAME. My php script gives back some links which I would like to open outside that IFRAME - as a part of some other CMS block on the homepage. The idea is to target (from my php script) the div of that CMS block which is already showing some data. Is that possible?

Comment: an html representation of the issue would help, along with better explanation as it pertains to the html....otherwise it's very unclear what you want

Comment: in `iframe` use `parent.functionName();` inside `<script>` tag.

Comment: You want to traget a div with PHP? That's not how things work. Maybe you want to target the *parent window*, in the sense that clicking on your link would open on the parent window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access `<div>` or any other element of `parent window` from its child `iframe`

USE:

```
var elem=window.parent.document.getElementById('target');
```

inside `<script>` tag of `iframe`'s document.

ex.

file: index.html (Give any name).

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="div_to_use_from_parent">Blah!</div>
<iframe src="xyz.php" width="xx" height="xx"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

file: xyz.php (same as src of iframe)

```
<?php 
echo<<<html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function do_blah(){
    var elem=window.parent.document.getElementById('div_to_use_from_parent');
    elem.innerHTML="iframe changed My Content!";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="do_blah();">
This is iframe
</body>
</html> 
html;
?>
```

OR

if you need to access element in `iframe` from `parent window`

USE:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('idOfIframe');
var frame = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var yourDiv= frame.getElementById('div_you_want');
```

inside `<script>` tag of `parent window`'s document.

ex.

file: index.html (Give any name).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
var iframe = document.getElementById('idOfIframe');
var frame = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var elem= frame.getElementById('div_from_iframe');
elem.innerHTML+="<br /> And Parent window added this!";
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div_to_use_from_parent">Blah!</div>
<iframe src="xyz.php" width="xx" height="xx"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

file: xyz.php (same as src of iframe)

```
<?php 
echo<<<html
<html>
<body>
<div id="div_from_iframe"> This div from iframe</div>
</body>
</html> 
html;
?>
```

`parent window` is the one in which original `html`(index.html) document along with your `iframe`(xyz.php) resides.

Hope it helps :-)!

Answer (score 1):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('idOfIframe');
var frame = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var yourDiv= frame.getElementById('div_you_want');
```

Answer (score 1):

From the page running inside the `<iframe>` you can refer to the parent page as `window.parent`, and perform actions as you normally would.

```
parent.document.getElementById('target_div').innerHTML = 'New content.';
```

Note JavaScript's cross-domain restrictions apply. You can only do that if both pages belong to the same domain.

In case of links, you can include to your `<a>` tags the attribute `target="_parent"`, or set it as base target to apply to all links.

```
<head>
    ...
    <base target="_parent">
</head>
```

You can also target a link to another `iframe`, all you have to do is set a `name="iframe_name"` to it and set `target="iframe_name"` to all links that should open in that area.