# iframe inside iframe and get information from parent using PHP

Tags: php, iframe

eBay auction with the following code:

```
<iframe width="1416" height="3384" frameborder="0" id="desc_ifr" src="http://adomain.com/mainframe">
<h1>the content</h1>other content 

     <iframe src="http://another_domain.com/frame.php">
     </iframe>

</iframe>
```

Through the frame.php content, I would like to go back to the parent frame with id desc_ifr for find keywords inside the H1 tags and do something when found.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842957/javascript-is-it-possible-to-target-div-of-another-file/24843100#24843100

Comment: how to create a variable for searching in h1 tags and do something when found something ?

Comment: The code you have is invalid. The content of an `<iframe>` element must be specified using the `src` or `srcdoc` attributes, not by giving it child elements.